# If $S$ is a subspace with basis $\mathcal B$, and $u$ and $v$ are in the set of $\mathcal B$, then $u + v$ is the set of $\mathcal B$.

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Given that a basis is the smallest set of vectors that is linearly independent and spans a subspace, I am unsure if $u + v$ is in the set $\mathcal B$. If my understanding of span is not incorrect, span includes all linear combinations of its vectors within the span. However, $u + v$, if included in the basis, makes it linearly dependent which would make the statement false. Is my understanding of span incorrect?

Comment: Yes. What you said can be rephrased to "$u+v$ is in the span of B, but $u+v$ should not be in B$, which is correct.

Comment: No, you're correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose  $u+v $ is in $\mathcal B $. Then note that  $1\cdot(u+v)-1\cdot u-1\cdot v+0\cdot (\text{other elements in $\mathcal B $})=0.$

But this contradicts the fact that the basis elements are linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

$-1u-1v+1(u+v)=0$

But $-1,-1,1$ are not zero, so they aren’t linearly independent. Your idea is correct